# How to quickly reassert a fact with multiple fields using a single variable in CLIPS

Tags: clips

Let's say I have this template:

```
(deftemplate TRIP::trip
   (multislot resort-sequence)
   (multislot place-sequence)
   (multislot days-distribution))
```

and this rule:

```
(defrule test
    ?p <- (trip (days-distribution $?days))
    =>
    ;change value of ?days
```

Now, since `?p` has 3 fields what I'm wondering is: Is it possible to reassert the facts ?p without having to bind separatly all the fields?

Something like this:
`(assert (trip ?p (days-distribution $?days)))`

Edit:
To Clarify,
from one `trip-fact` I need to create multiple ones so I cannot modify the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `modify` function but you need to pay attention to looping rules. Your rule above, once fired, would loop indefinitely as a newly modified `trip` fact would activate the rule over and over again.

```
In [1]: (deftemplate trip 
      :   (multislot resort-sequence) 
      :   (multislot place-sequence) 
      :   (multislot days-distribution))                                                                                                                                                                    

In [2]: (defrule test 
      :   ?loop-prevention <- (new-trip) 
      :   ?p <- (trip (days-distribution $?days)) 
      :   => 
      :   (retract ?loop-prevention) 
      :   (modify ?p (days-distribution 1 2 3)))                                                                                                                                                  

In [3]: (assert (trip (resort-sequence a b c) (place-sequence d e f) (days-distribution 22 23 24)))                                                                                     
(trip (resort-sequence a b c) (place-sequence d e f) (days-distribution 22 23 24))

In [4]: (assert (new-trip))                                                                                                                                                                                 
(new-trip)

In [5]: (facts)                                                                                                                                                                                             
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (trip (resort-sequence a b c) (place-sequence d e f) (days-distribution 22 23 24))
f-2     (new-trip)
For a total of 3 facts.

In [6]: (agenda)                                                                                                                                                                                            
0      test: f-2,f-1
For a total of 1 activation.

In [7]: (run)                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [8]: (facts)                                                                                                                                                                                             
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-3     (trip (resort-sequence a b c) (place-sequence d e f) (days-distribution 1 2 3))
For a total of 2 facts.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however there has been a misunderstanding (it's my fault)! From one `trip-fact` I need to create multiple ones so I cannot modify the first

Comment: Use duplicate rather than modify.

Comment: @GaryRiley fantastic! Thank you so much!